# WSO2 ESB VFS: Pick up one File at a Time

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I have created a simple vfs proxy which consumes a file and places it on the JMS queue.  I want to be able to pick up one file at a time.  I have my pollinterval set for every 10 minutes.

Are there any properties or settings I am missing to control this functionality?

Sample Proxy Below

```
        <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="VFSImportProxy"                  transports="https,http,vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
    <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log separator="," />
         <sequence key="smooks_sequence" />
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <send>
            <endpoint key="MessageStore_EP" />
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence />
      <faultSequence />
   </target>
        <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">600000</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://locationpickup/local2</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">smb://location/archive</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">smb://location/failed</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <enableSec />
       </proxy>
```

Comment: what is the point of getting one at a time and placing it in a queue?
Anyway AFAIK there's no any property to make your requirement happens.
It take all the files in given FileNamePattern in each poll interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the parameter name is transport.vfs.FileProcessCount and it's available in version 4.8.0 and up.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/VFS+Transport